# How to prove $\inf_{z\in{C}}||z-x||=\min_{u\in{cl}({c})}||u-x||$, where $C$ is a closed set.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I want to prove that for a closed set $C$, we have the following:

$\inf_{z\in{C}}||{z-x}||=\min_{u\in{cl}{(c)}}|{u-x}||$.

I was thinking of using Weierstrass Theorem, but one of the assumptions in that theorem is that set C is bounded, but we do not have that condition.
Is there any suggestion on to how to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: $C\subset{\mathbb{R}}^n$

Comment: Where does $C$ live?

Comment: @User203940 I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\alpha := \inf\{ \|z-x\| \ | \ z \in C\}.$ Let $(z_n) \subseteq C$ be such that $\|z_n - x\| \rightarrow \alpha$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. We can find sufficiently large $N$ so that for all $n \geq N$ we have $\|z_n - x\| < \alpha + \epsilon.$ Without loss of generality, assume that it holds for all $n$ (otherwise just create a new sequence). Now we see that $(z_n) \subseteq \{y \in C \ | \ \|y-x\| \leq \alpha + \epsilon\}$, which is closed and bounded (hence compact). We can take a subsequence $(z_{n_j}) \subseteq \{y \in C \ | \ \|y-x\| \leq \alpha + \epsilon\}$ which converges to some $z$. Furthermore, we know that $z$ must be such that $\|z-x\| = \alpha$. Since $C$ is closed and we assumed that $(z_n) \subseteq C$, we get that $z \in C$, so the infimum is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Hint on using Weierstrass theorem: assume that $C$ is closed and non-empty, i.e. there exists $z_0\in C$, and consider the set
$$
C_0=C\cap\{z\colon \|z-x\|\le\|z_0-x\|\}.
$$
The result will follow from the Weierstrass theorem if you manage to work out the following fact
$$
\inf_{z\in C}\|z-x\|=\inf_{z\in C_0}\|z-x\|.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Would you mind giving a bit of guidance on what I should do with the fact in the last line, please?

Comment: @SpringBreeze The new set $C_0$ can be proven to be compact, then the minimum over  $C_0$ exists. It is left to relate it to the original set.